# Python error "name 'self' is not defined"

Tags: python, self, pyscripter

I am trying to reference a variable from a class inside a method, I tried it without self but that gave me the error "name 'one' is not defined".

```
class hello(object):
    self.one = 1
    def method(self):
        print one

food = hello()
food.method()
```

Comment: I believe you want to print self.one.

Comment: read about scoping rules.  As far as I can tell you have no reason to think that the unqualified reference to `one` would work and you seem to be wondering why Python isn't acting like some other language without actually doing any research.

Answer (score 11):

Do you want to define a class variable or an instance variable?

For a variable defined within the scope of the instance / object use:

```
class hello(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1

    def method(self):
        print self.one

food = hello()
food.method()
```

For a class variable:

```
class hello(object):
    one = 1

    def method(self):
        print hello.one

food = hello()
food.method()
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be `print self.one` instead of of `print one` and `one = 1` instead of `self.one = 1`

Comment: Well.... the error will be coming from `self.one = 1` at the class level... so this isn't quite right...

Comment: Now you're subtly hiding a class level as an instance level which is just going to lead to more confusion... 3rd time lucky?

Comment: @JonClements I don't quite get it. I'm assuming OP wants `one` declared on the class level.

Comment: Then access it via the class not an instance...

Comment: Well, that's a choice OP has to make. Maybe (s)he's just trying out stuff. And there could be a good reason to do that in production.

Comment: If the OP was aware of the choices, I doubt they'd have asked the question... So at best, while this "will work" - it doesn't explain why it would or even give a hint as to the difference between class or instance attributes... etc...